# Setting up Rocket-chip for Questasim and getting error while compiling jtag_vpi.c

Tags: riscv

I have downloaded Rocket-chip from GIT, installed RISC-V tools and Generated the verilog files for Rocket core. Now I want to run the assembly tests that are given but I dont have VCS instead I have Questasim. I modified the Makefile to use Questasim but the two C++ files that needs to be compiled SimDTM.cc and jtag_vpi.c are giving error.

In Questa we cant compile C files along with verilog files instead we need to compile this separately and generate *.so file and link with -pli while simulating.

Here when I'm compiling jtag_vpi.c I'm getting and error saying invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'PLI_INT32. I'm compiling it with the below command and the error I'm getting is also pasted below.

> g++ jtag_vpi.c -I $RISCV/include -I $MTI_HOME/questasim/include -std=c++11 -W -shared -Bsymblic -fPIC

.

.

> riscv/rocket-chip/csrc/jtag_vpi.c:398:2: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘PLI_INT32 (*)(t_cb_data*) {aka int (*)(t_cb_data*)}’ [-fpermissive]

Line 398:2 is just an end of a function and the error is shown at the end of each such function.

Any help will be useful.

Thanks in advance.